# Delphi 10.4 FMX App replacing Application.ProcessMessage() with Thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am trying to run a simple example Delphi 10.4 FMX program that does away with `Application.ProcessMessages()` as suggested by [Android and Application.ProcessMessages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775196/) and [Does application.processmessages behaviour differ between VCL and FMX?](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/658-does-applicationprocessmessages-behaviour-differ-between-vcl-and-fmx/).

The button simply updates the label 3 times. Following [Background Operations on Delphi Android, with Threads and Timers](https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2014_may_background_delphi_android_threads.html), it works as expected with one level, but not two levels of change.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?  I have left the code with `Application.ProcessMessages()` to show the desired effect.

```pascal
function Measure1sec(wait: integer): boolean;
var
  sw: TStopwatch;
begin
  sw := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  while sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < wait do sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  Result := TRUE;
end;
    
procedure TForm1.EndProgress(Sender: TObject);
var
  Thread: TThread;
begin
  Measure1sec(500);
  label1.text := 'orange';
end;
    
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Thread: TThread;
begin
  {
  //////////////////  Using Application.ProcessMessages //////////////
  label1.text := 'apple';
  // Application.ProcessMessages;   // with this works without not
  Measure1sec(500);
  label1.text := 'orange';
  // Application.ProcessMessages;   // with this works without not
  Measure1sec(500);
  label1.text := 'done';
  // Application.ProcessMessages;   // with this works without not
  Measure1sec(500);
  }
    
  //////////////////  Using Threads //////////////////////////////////
  Thread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current,
        procedure
        begin
          label1.text := 'apple';
        end
      );
    end
  );
  Thread.OnTerminate := EndProgress;
  Thread.Start;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your `Measure1sec()` function is inefficient. Instead of using `TStopWatch` in a busy loop, it can be re-written to use [`TThread.Sleep()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Sleep) instead, eg:

```pascal
procedure Measure1sec(wait: integer); inline;
begin
  TThread.Sleep(wait);
end;
```

In which case, you may as well just get rid of `Measure1sec()` altogether, eg:

```pascal
label1.text := 'apple';
// Application.ProcessMessages;
TThread.Sleep(500);
label1.text := 'orange';
// Application.ProcessMessages;
TThread.Sleep(500);
label1.text := 'done';
// Application.ProcessMessages;
TThread.Sleep(500);
```

Now, to answer your question - you are not seeing all of the label updates because your worker thread performs only 1 label update.  For what you are attempting, you would need to have the thread perform multiple label updates, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          label1.text := 'apple';
        end
      );
      TThread.Sleep(500);
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          label1.text := 'orange';
        end
      );
      TThread.Sleep(500);
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          label1.text := 'done';
        end
      );
      TThread.Sleep(500);
    end
  ).Start;
end;
```

However, this is largely a waste of a worker thread, since most of the work is being performed in the main UI thread.  As such, I would suggest getting rid of the `TThread` altogether, use [`TThread.ForceQueue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue) instead, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Step1;
end;

procedure TForm1.Step1;
begin
  label1.text := 'apple';
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil, Step2, 500);
end;

procedure TForm1.Step2;
begin
  label1.text := 'orange';
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil, Step3, 500);
end;

procedure TForm1.Step3;
begin
  label1.text := 'done';
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label1.text := 'apple';
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      label1.text := 'orange';
    end,
    500
  );
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      label1.text := 'done';
    end,
    1000
  );
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, this is perfect.  I think I will keep the thread, your middle solution,  as I need to do more than the ui but wanted a simple example. I have accepted the answer.